# Which package index did pip just install from?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, scipy

I am trying to install numpy and some other python packages in their intel optimized versions. They are not distributed as wheels via PyPI, but only via anaconda cloud. But that index doesn't contain all the dependencies, so PyPI must *also* be used. The command to run is

```
python -m pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/intel/simple --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple numpy
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a version race, and if PyPI has a newer version of NumPy, I won't get the intel-version of NumPy. To check if I got the right NumPy version, I run `python -c "import numpy; numpy.show_config()"` and verify it has MKL support. For SciPy, I don't know of a corresponding command. I have tried this a few times now, and it is using a cached scipy version, so I don't get any information from the pip output specifying which repository it is using.

How can I see *after the installation has been completed* which repository was used?

Comment: "*How can I see after the installation has been completed which repository was used?*" See the corresponding directories `*.dist-info`. In the file `METADATA` there is a field `Download-URL`

Comment: ok cool. I found the `*.dist-info` by running `pip show numpy`, and navigating to the install location of numpy. However, the `METADATA` file says in the free text that I should download from anaconda. This shows I indeed installed the intel-variant. But the `Download-URL` is still pointing to PyPI, so the `Download-URL` field sems not reliable.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the best you can get.

Comment: Ok thanks. Its still a good step in the right direction, as the readme text verified I had the right package installed. :)